# Flutter: Difference between Raw Material Button and Material Button

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

**Hello There Everyone!**
How's your day going? I hope its brilliant <3

I need a little bit of your help here, I've been using Raw Material Button and Material button lot in my code, But I don't know what is the difference between **Raw Material button** and **Material Button?**.

Because they look similar while using them.

Thanks in Advance **<3**

Answer (score 6):

From docs attached to the classes:

> `MaterialButton` is utility class for building Material buttons that depend on the ambient `ButtonTheme` and `Theme`.

and

> `RawMaterialButton` does not use the current `Theme` or `ButtonTheme` to compute default values for unspecified parameters.

And that's really it - the difference is in the default values. Under the hood MaterialButton is using RawMaterialButton

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    final ButtonThemeData buttonTheme = ButtonTheme.of(context);

    return RawMaterialButton(
      onPressed: onPressed,
      onHighlightChanged: onHighlightChanged,
      // so many properties here...
      child: child,
      materialTapTargetSize: materialTapTargetSize ?? theme.materialTapTargetSize,
    );
}
```

Comment: Sir Thanks You So very much, really helpful especially with Code <3

Answer (score 1):

**From official Flutter Docs**

**MaterialButton class**

> A utility class for building Material buttons that depend on the
> ambient ButtonTheme and Theme.
>
> The button's size will expand to fit the child widget, if necessary.
>
> MaterialButtons whose onPressed handler is null will be disabled. To
> have an enabled button, make sure to pass a non-null value for
> onPressed.

**RawMaterialButton class**

> This class does not use the current Theme or ButtonTheme to compute
> default values for unspecified parameters.
>
> It's intended to be used
> for custom Material buttons that optionally incorporate defaults from
> the themes or from app-specific sources.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It helped really :) :)

Answer (score 1):

`MaterialButton` class is used for building buttons that depend on ambient `ButtonTheme` and `Theme`. On the other hand, `RawMaterialButton`s does not use `ButtonTheme` or `Theme`. 
According to documentation,

> *RawMaterialButton* does not use *ButtonTheme* or *Theme* to compute default values for unspecified parameters. It's intended to be used for custom *Material* *buttons* that optionally incorporate defaults from the themes or from app-specific sources.

Refer the documentation for more details [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RawMaterialButton-class.html).

Comment: Thank You So very much. I'll look into the doc details if necessary.